# c# DataBinding not working

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a class:

```
public partial class MapPoint
{
    public double longtitude { get; set; }
    public double lattitude { get; set; }
    public string oblast { get; set; }
    public string addr { get; set; }
    public string sid { get; set; }
}
```

and form2 with some textboxes. I try to use data binding to bind data:
In form2 constructor

```
bs = new BindingSource();
textBox1.DataBinding.Add( "Text", bs, "longtitude" );
textBox5.DataBinding.Add( "Text", bs, "addr" );
```

and before form shown (from other module called):

```
private MapPoint _pt;
public MapPoint pt 
{ 
    get { return _pt; } 
    set 
    {
            _pt = value; // here normal MapPoint class passed
            bs.DataSource = pt;
            bs.ResetBindings(false); // or true
    }
}
```

In form2 all works fine. I create another form (form3) and copy-paste code, but not all fields works and filled with data from record. 
What wrong with form3? Why not all fields works?

Comment: What is `_pt`, `pt` and `value` ?

Comment: private MapPoint _pt; public MapPoint pt { get { return _pt; } set { _pt = value; bs.DataSource = pt; bs.ResetBindings(false); }

Comment: Don't comment, edit your question.

Comment: _but not all fields works_ - what this mean? Exception thrown, wrong values. If really copied a code, form3 called/opened in exactly same way as form2 - it should work. Based on your examples and provided information form3 should work in same manner as form2

Comment: not working - its meat, that all not textboxes filled with data. Some filled, some - not.

Comment: Based on your example only fields of `longtitude` and `addr` should be filled. Which one is empty?

Comment: Then in the setter of `pt` - you have line `bs.DataSource = pt;` I think it should be `bs.DataSource = _pt;`

Comment: No difference - pt returns _pt. I try to change and its also not working.

Comment: longitude works (in all forms), addr - only on form2.

Comment: Finallyy I found solution - I delete textboxes and place it again (new, not copy-paste) and all works now. Dont understand, why copypasted textboxes not working.